# Get City Names of a Country/State

Tags: google-maps, region, countries

On Lot of websites we select country from a select list and next select list shows us the list of cities of that country. I have am trying to search method provided by any api which gives the name of cities when I pass the country name. In any language.

Also I have been unable to find any free sql table like

```
Country          City
----------------------
Australia        Perth
Australia        Sydney 
Japan            Tokyo
```

My ideal result would be

```
Country          City         Lat        Long
----------------------------------------------
Australia        Perth        3.35       14.7
Australia        Sydney       3.36       14.62
Japan            Tokyo        4.2        12.8
```

**Update :** We can find all countries list easily, even we also can get all cities in the world, but cities are not found along with country names, so we can not determine what city belongs to which country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're looking for something like http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/.

I haven't used it but often heard about it, and it seems to be a good product.

Comment: No sorry. I have mentioned clearly. I need to know country vise cities list. I have found countries aslo cities. But need to make two tables and in cities table country will be foriegn key

Comment: Here is the database : http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/csv It seems to be a countries table and a cities table, which are what you need.

Comment: No I have found cities dear. But need city vs country. City with country name. Which is not given there

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong, but "GeoIP City Edition CSV Database Field" gives you city name and country code & "GeoIP Country Edition CSV Database Fields" gives you country code and country name. So you can make the link with a sql join.

Comment: I m not get helped yet so not convinced as well but +1. For continuous answers and good reasoning